# Htaccess rewrite to file located up one level

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I have an htaccess in a subdomain with the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^feed([0-9]+)$ ../image.php?id=$1 [L]
```

So basically I want to redirect requests from feed which is located in a subdomain to image.php file which is located in the main domain (just one directory above). Using `../` doesn't seem to work like in PHP.

So how can I rewrite to file in the parent directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the sounds of it, you are already in the document root of your subdomain, which is probably defined in its own virtual host (which happens to point to a subdirectory off the main domains document root).

Unfortunately, you can't internally rewrite above/outside the document root using mod_rewrite in `.htaccess`. In `.htaccess` the `RewriteRule` *substitution* takes a URL-path only, not a filesystem path. However, you can do this if you are using mod_rewrite directly in the server config. In the server config you can specify a filesystem path as the substitution (you would need to explicitly include the full path, you can't use a relative path like `../image.php`).

Alternatively, in `.htaccess` you might be able to proxy the request from your subdomain to the maindomain using mod_proxy with mod_rewrite. However, this might still require some server configuration. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^feed([0-9]+)$ http://maindomain.com/image.php?id=$1 [P]
```